# S3 Bucket gives InvalidArgument (client): Unsupported value for canned acl 'private' - for put file operation with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading an image to s3 bucket using laravel. Delete operation and listing the object is working fine but when I'm trying to upload the images it is giving an error. Can't troubleshoot the issue. here is the error response.

```
Error executing "PutObject" on "https://weddingdotmelbourne.s3.us-west-002.backblazeb2.com/YoPDX.txt"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://weddingdotmelbourne.s3.us-west-002.backblazeb2.com/YoPDX.txt` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: ◀
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
    <Message>Unsupporte (truncated...)
 InvalidArgument (client): Unsupported value for canned acl 'private' - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
    <Message>Unsupported value for canned acl 'private'</Message>
</Error>
```

**EDIT**
Here is the simple testing code I'm trying.

```
Route::get('s3-putfile', function () {
    try {
        $name = Str::random(5) . ".txt";
        $putFileAs = Storage::disk('s3')->put($name, "Hello this is the test file");
        dd($putFileAs);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return ($e->getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that is doing the upload/PUT?

Comment: Hey @Jordan please check the question I have editited the code.

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me as well while using Backblaze. You can configure Laravel to upload files as "public" which is needed when your Backblaze bucket is set to be public.

In `config/filesystems.php`:

```
'disks' => [
  's3' => [
    ...
    'visibility' => 'public',
  ],
],
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Backblaze. As you can see in their documentation you can't set the type "public" or "private" on a single item level.
In your case the "folder" is public and Laravel tries to write a file as "private" and that causes the error.

I have solved the problem in setting the whole Bucket to private.